# Python requests vs java webservices

Tags: java, python, web-services, python-requests, legacy

I have a legacy web application `sys-1` written in cgi that currently uses a TCP socket connection to communicated with another system `sys-2`. `Sys-1` sends out the data in the form a unix string. Now `sys-2` is upgrading to java web service which in turn requires us to upgrade. Is there any way to upgrade involving minimal changes to the existing legacy code. I am contemplating the creating of a code block which gets the output of `Sys-1` and changes it into a format required by `Sys-2` and vice versa.

While researching, I found two ways of doing this:

1. By using the "requests" library in python.
2. Go with the java webservices.

I am new to Java web services and have some knowledge in python. Can anyone advise if this method works and which is a better way to opt from a performance and maintenance point of view? Any new suggestions are also welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to upgrade involving minimal changes to the existing legacy code.

The solution mentioned, adding a conversion layer outside of the application, would have the least impact on the existing code base (in that it does not change the existing code base).

> Can anyone advise if this method works

Would writing a Legacy-System-2 to Modern-System-2 converter work? Yes. You could write this in any language you feel comfortable in. Web Services are Web Services, it matters not what they are implemented in. Same with TCP sockets.

> better way to opt from a performance

How important is performance? If this is used once in a blue moon then who cares. Adding a box between services will make the communication between services slower. If implemented well and running close to either System 1 or System 2 likely not much slower.

> maintenance point of view?

Adding additional infrastructure adds complexity thus more problems with maintenance. It also adds a new chunk of code to maintain, and if System 1 needs to use System 2 in a new way you have two lots of code to maintain (Legacy System 1 and Legacy/Modern converter).

> Any new suggestions are also welcome!

How bad is legacy? Could you rip the System-1-to-System-2 code out into some nice interfaces that you could update to use Modern System 2 without too much pain? Long term this would have a lower overall cost, but would have a (potentially significantly) larger upfront cost. So you have to make a decision on what, for your organisation, is more important. Time To Market or Long Term Maintenance. No one but your organisation can answer that.

Comment: Thanks for the insights ! @mlk

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add a man-in-the-middle. A socket server who gets the unix strings, parse them into a sys-2 type of message and send it to sys-2. That could be an option to not re-write all calls between the two systems.